# Programmatic access to Brother ADS-1000W

Tags: python, scanning

I've got a Brother ADS-1000W receipt scanner and using the ControlCenter4 software it works great. However I would like to be able automate the scanning process and I can't find any pointers/clues on where to get access to the ADS-1000W specific features. With the ControlCenter4 software, I can have the scanner deskew images. It also scans to an arbitrary length and width (matching the scanned receipt). I'm assuming this is being handled by the scanner, but it may be happening in the ControlCenter4 software. These features specifically don't seem to be accessible in the TWAIN interface. I tried using [TWAINCommander 3](http://www.jse.de/products.html#twaincommander2) and it doesn't show the deskew and arbitrary size features in the TWAIN interface.

I've got both Linux and Windows machines available and I'm cool with a commandline solution or an SDK that I have to write software to implement. If it's an SDK, I prefer Python.

I know this is somewhat open-ended, but hoping someone can point in a direction for further research.

Comment: It's doubtful that the TWAIN supports image processing like de-skewing, since it's primarily an interface specification for transferring (image) data between devices and computers. This implies you'll need to do that sort of thing in your own code, likely by using some existing image processing library—of which there are many. Unfortunaetly asking for recommendations is off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @martineau Is arbitrary scan size also something that would not be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this question: The ADS-1000W supports scanning to FTP. If PDF is selected, then the scanner supports the de-skew option, so I installed vsftpd on my linux box and used Python to process the files as their uploaded.